# Bootstrap multi-line button with badge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project with bootstrap and I'm trying to figure out how to get a button that shows:
-Text left aligned (pull-left makes sense here I think)
-A badge right aligned with a number (pull right makes sense here)

This works great but the problem is most of my buttons have names that are ideal for a two-line button. Everything looks great on one line but as soon as the text gets too long or the button gets too short, it kicks the text to another line and the top text looks centered instead of pulled left. This looks good:

```
<div style="width:300px;margin:10px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="font-weight:bold;white-space:normal;">
        <span class="pull-left">Under Investigation </span><span class="badge pull-right">5</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

This looks bad (button is too narrow, text on top doesn't pull left):

```
<div style="width:150px;margin:10px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="font-weight:bold;white-space:normal;display:inline-flex;">
        <span class="pull-left">Under Investigation </span><span class="badge pull-right">5</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjerskine/ay9L512h/2/

Solution: 
I ended up having to wrap the text in another div which is fine and works great when the window resizes. The text kicks to two lines and the badge stays on one line. I'll end up writing this with proper classes but here's the solution for anyone with a similar question:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="font-weight:bold;">
        <div class="pull-left" style="text-align:left;width:calc(100% - 30px);white-space:normal;overflow:hidden;">
            Under Investigation
        </div>
        <span class="badge pull-right" style="display:inline-flex;">5</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: try with     display: inline-flex;

Comment: inline-flex fixed the problem with the badge getting kicked to the third line. The text is still messed up though (see fiddle). The "Under" in "Under Investigation" is almost centered while "Investigation" is pulled left like it should be.

Comment: do you want like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ay9L512h/3/

Comment: It's in a grid column with col-md-2. There are six buttons in the row. The problem is, before it snaps everything vertically, the buttons get too small and the text should get kicked to two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text-align:left` on that button.

```
button span.pull-left {
  text-align: left
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ay9L512h/5/)

Comment: Pretty much got me there thanks! Ended up wrapping it in a container with the text-align: left.

Comment: @user3060454 Great! Glad it helped.